# Where to take perspective.lua for Corona sdk and how to install it?

Tags: android, lua, camera, coronasdk

I understand that perspective.lua will help to create the camera in the game? But where to find it, how to download and how to install?

*please help make the camera chasing the object*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it from [Github](https://gist.github.com/GymbylCoding/8675733) and require it in your code.

Comment: Try on Corona forum [Gymbyl Coding](https://forums.coronalabs.com/forum/604-gymbyl-coding/?prune_day=100&sort_by=Z-A&sort_key=last_post&topicfilter=all) and analyze code from link to [Github](https://gist.github.com/GymbylCoding/8675733) with library. You find there example od usage.

Comment: Try one of these links [How to create Infinite Scrolling background](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/48885-how-to-create-infinite-scrolling-background/) or [Create an Endless Scrolling Background with Corona SDK](http://gamebuildingtools.com/corona-sdk/create-endless-scrolling-background-corona-sdk) or [Background infinite using corona sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828279/background-infinite-using-corona-sdk). Good luck :)